# transform for in loop to while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

i have this assignment in a basic programming course where i need to transform this code using while loop instead of for loop, but i dont know how to doit

this is my code so far

```
def read_txt(file_txt):
    file = open(file_txt, "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    return lines


file_txt = input("file: ")

lines = read_txt(file_txt)
for l in lines:
    asd = l.split(",")
    length = len(asd)
    score = 0
    for i in range(1, length):
         score += int(asd[i])
    average = score / (length-1)
    print(asd[0], average)
```

```
file text is like this

edward,4,3,1,2
sara,5,4,1,0
```

Comment: Maybe use an incrementing index and and keep looping *while* it is within the bounds of your lines list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def read_txt(file_txt):
    file = open(file_txt, "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    return lines


file_txt = input("file: ")

lines = read_txt(file_txt)
lines.reverse()

while lines:
    l = lines.pop()
    asd = l.split(",")
    length = len(asd)
    score = 0
    i = 1
    while i < length:
         score += int(asd[i])
         i += 1
    average = score / (length-1)
    print(asd[0], average)
```

Now in this while loop, it will iterate through lines until lines is empty. it will pop out items one by one.

Comment: but you are using a for loop in the while loop :(

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

For loops are more suitable for iterating over lines in files than while loops.  Few improvements here are, (1) use the builtin `sum` instead of manually adding up scores, and (2) don't read all lines in file at once if the files are too big.

```
file_txt = input("file: ")
with open(file_txt) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        name, scores = line.split(',', maxsplit=1)
        scores = scores.split(',')
        avg = sum(int(s) for s in scores) / len(scores)
        print(f'{name} {avg}')
```

As you see above the check for `if not line` to determine if we have reached the end of file in a while loop, this is not needed in for loop as that implements the `__iter__` protocol.

Python 3.8 walrus operator makes that slightly easier with::

```
file_txt = input("file: ")
with open(file_txt) as f:
    while line := f.readline():
        name, scores = line.split(',', maxsplit=1)
        scores = scores.split(',')
        avg = sum(int(s) for s in scores) / len(scores)
        print(f'{name} {avg}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gives the exact same output without using any for loop.

```
filename = input("file: ")
with open(filename) as f:
    f = f.readlines()
    n = []
    while f:
        v = f.pop()
        if v[-1] == '\n':
            n.append(v.strip('\n'))
        else:
            n.append(v)
    d = {}
    while n:
        v = n.pop()
        v = v.split(',')
        d[v[0]] = v[1:]
    d_k = list(d.keys())
    d_k.sort(reverse=True)
    while d_k:
        v = d_k.pop()
        p = d[v]
        n = []
        while p:
            a = p.pop()
            a = int(a)
            n.append(a)
        print(str(v), str(sum(n)/len(n)))
```

Output:

```
edward 2.5
sara 2.5
```